# Using Stream in Java with Multiple Map

Tags: java, java-stream

I am having following class in Java

```
class School{

    int id;
    Children C

    public getChildren() return C;

}

class Children{
    String name;

    public getname() return name;

}

class Key{

    List<School> S;

    public get Schoollist(){ return S}

}
```

I am using the following code:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(
          "Names",
              key.getSchoollist()
              .stream()
              .filter(Objects::nonNull)
              .map(School::getChildren)
              .map(Children::getname)
              .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Java is not allowing me to use two map, how to get children name using Stream.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Why not removing the two maps and use *.map(school -> school.getChildren().getName())* instead? Good luck.

Comment: Please post actual methods instead of `public getname() return name;` and `public getChildren() return C;`

Comment: when you say `getChildren`, isn't that suppose to return a `List`?

Comment: What do you mean by "Java is not allowing"? You get compilation error? If so please post it. Or you get runtime exception? Then post it.

Comment: it's compilation error that it can resolve  `getname` method

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(
          "Names",
              key.getSchoollist()
              .stream()
              .filter(Objects::nonNull)
              .map(e -> e.getChildren().getname())
              .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```